# How to adjust the position of an element when it is adjusted by a filter or other reasons

Tags: html, css, filter

I applied a drop shadow filter to a image and now the image is offset by about 10 pixels.

Is there a way to keep the filter from adjusting the position of the image?

```css
#Image_3 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  outline: 1px dashed #000000;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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") 0 0 no-repeat" id="Image_3">
```

**Update:**
It was an issue on my end. The image already had a drop shadow. The filter did not adjust the position of the image. I changed the title of the question slightly.

Comment: share the code ... drop-shadow shouldn't move the image

Comment: ^ yes please show the code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow is a basic playground and the image does not move with drop-shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's unlikely that your filter is moving your image, just taking up additional space with the drop shadow.  you can either add additional padding/margin on the right and bottom sides of your image to account for the drop shadow, or offset the image top/left position to counterbalance the shadow

try

```
#Image_1 {
  /* other styles */
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

or

```
#Image_1 {
  /* other styles */
  transform: translate(-5px, -5px);
}
```